# How to setup Github SSH login when host username and Github account are different?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have the following "fake" configuration:

- A server: server1
- A username in server1: user1
- A private Github repository: repo1
- A Github account: user2

I have created a SSH key for `user1` on `server1` by running:

```
ssh-keygen
```

I have added the `id_rsa.pub` key to the Github account: `user2`.

I have tested SSH connection from `server1` logged in as `user1` to Github by running the following commands:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

Both command were successful meaning I can connect. As soon as I try to run: `git pull` I being asked for `username` and `password`, why?

I am trying to avoid enter the username/password each time I need to perform a pull/commit/push.

The repository is configured as `https`:

```
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/company/repo.git
```

Should I change the remote URL from `https` to `ssh`? What I am missing?

Note: is "fake" for not to use real names but the configuration exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the remote URL to SSH to ensure your SSH key is used: `git@github.com:company/repo.git`.

The easiest way is probably:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:company/repo.git
```